# How to check that the artifactory cleanup plugin is working as exepected?

Tags: plugins, artifactory

We executed curl command to ran the cleanup plugin, but it didn't display any results

Enabled the logger name in `"/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/logback.xml"` and executed the curl command to ran the artifactsCleanup plugin.

Curl command is executing successfully, but not sure whether it’s really doing any cleanup as there are no cleanup results in the output.

And nothing is written to the cleanup log file.

```
-rw-r----- 1 0 Jun 22 15:50 artifactory-cleanup.log
```

======================

> $ curl -X POST -v -u admin:password "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/cleanup?params=timeUnit=month;timeInterval=1;repos=libs-release-local;dryRun=true;paceTimeMS=2000;disablePropertiesSupport=true"
> Trying 127.0.0.1:8082...
> Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8082 (#0)
> Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /artifactory/api/plugins/execute/cleanup?params=timeUnit=month;timeInterval=1;repos=libs-release-local;dryRun=true;paceTimeMS=2000;disablePropertiesSupport=true HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: /
> Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> < Content-Length: 0
> Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

===========

We have enabled the logger and specified the level to "info" as mentioned below,

`<logger name="artifactCleanup" level="info"/>`

I can see only below information in the artifactory-service.log, after running the above mentioned curl command for running the cleanup plugin.

==========================

> 2021-06-25T09:00:27.941Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [6e717cba6e9f053f] [a.e.EventsLogCleanUpService:69] [art-exec-1 ] - Starting cleanup of old events from event log
> 2021-06-25T09:00:32.644Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [6e717cba6e9f053f] [.e.EventsLogCleanUpService:100] [art-exec-1 ] - Cleanup of old events from event log finished
> 2021-06-25T09:59:50.385Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [49a51a47e4f692d6] [aseBundleCleanupServiceImpl:84] [art-exec-5 ] - Starting to cleanup incomplete Release Bundles
> 2021-06-25T09:59:50.404Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [49a51a47e4f692d6] [aseBundleCleanupServiceImpl:90] [art-exec-5 ] - Finished incomplete Release Bundles cleanup
> 2021-06-25T10:48:16.556Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [36e8ebacb2d9e1eb] [ager$LogbackConfigWatchDog:147] [logback-watchdog ] - Reloaded logback config from: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/logback.xml.
> 2021-06-25T10:50:54.393Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [754f8c87874506df] [o.a.a.p.PluginsAddonImpl:121 ] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Reloading plugins
> 2021-06-25T10:57:38.954Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:32] [Stream_1624611588307] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
> 2021-06-25T10:57:39.563Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:32] [Stream_1624611589563] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
> 2021-06-25T10:57:39.765Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:32] [Stream_1624611589555] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
> 2021-06-25T10:57:41.758Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:32] [Stream_1624611596743] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
> 2021-06-25T10:59:08.355Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [ ] [ffectedConfigStreamObserver:32] [Stream_1624611588307] - publishing full invalidation and attempting to resubscribe to affected configuration changes
> 2021-06-25T10:59:50.386Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [9e98497d5e8e7824] [aseBundleCleanupServiceImpl:84] [art-exec-1 ] - Starting to cleanup incomplete Release Bundles
> 2021-06-25T10:59:50.389Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [9e98497d5e8e7824] [aseBundleCleanupServiceImpl:90] [art-exec-1 ] - Finished incomplete Release Bundles cleanup

====================

Reloaded the plugin as well using REST API.

`curl -v -u admin:xxxxx -X POST http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/plugins/reload`

We can't see the any output whether it's really doing any cleanup or not.

Answer (score 0):

What is the plugin being run here? Also when the plugin was added to Artifactory was the [reload plugin REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/jfrog/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ReloadPlugins) ran? What is the curl command run and what is the output seen?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [ArtifactCleanup](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup) User Plugin. Can you confirm if your api is running on 8082? For our Artifactory, api is running on 8081, and ui on 8082 (Artifactory version 7x).
I tested the query, and this works for us.

```
curl -X POST -v -u admin:password "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/cleanup?params=months=36;repos=npm-local-repo;dryRun=true;paceTimeMS=2000;disablePropertiesSupport=true"
```

Here we are looking for Artifacts that are not downloaded since 3 years in our npm repo.

You should see the logs in console.log file.

> 2021-08-10T18:18:30.226Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [39dadab89e78897 ]
> [artifactCleanup:62            ] [http-nio-8081-exec-3] - Deprecated
> month parameter is still in use, please use the new timeInterval
> parameter instead! 2021-08-10T18:18:30.227Z [jfrt ] [INFO ]
> [39dadab89e78897 ] [artifactCleanup:160           ]
> [http-nio-8081-exec-3] - Starting artifact cleanup for repositories
> [npm-local-repo], until 36 months ago with pacing interval 2000 ms,
> dryrun: true, disablePropertiesSupport: true 2021-08-10T18:18:30.227Z
> [jfrt ] [INFO ] [39dadab89e78897 ] [artifactCleanup:173           ]
> [http-nio-8081-exec-3] - Removing all artifacts not downloaded since
> 2018/08/10 11:18